# Java,SQLSERVER syntax

Tags: java, sql-server

Here is the code that is being generated when I run the Java class the page displays correctly with the information but there is an error in the log file.

java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
Java Code:

  sql2 = " SELECT COUNT(*)  CNT FROM ( SELECT UPPER(SOURCECODE)  as SRCCODE
           FROM  T1 WHERE  (PRODUCTTYPE LIKE '%card%') 
           AND ORDER_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'"+ddet.getStartDate()+"') AND   
           CONVERT(DATETIME,'"+ddet.getEndDate()+"')   
           AND (UPPER(SOURCECODE) IS NOT NULL)  GROUP BY            
           UPPER(SOURCECODE)) AS T";
SQL Generated:
  SELECT COUNT(*)  CNT FROM ( 
  SELECT UPPER(SOURCECODE)  as SRCCODE FROM T1 WHERE 
  (PRODUCTTYPE LIKE '%card%') AND 
   ORDER_DATE BETWEEN   CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/01/2012') AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/27/2013')
   AND (UPPER(SOURCECODE) IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY  UPPER(SOURCECODE)
) AS T
```

Comment: Without knowing the purpose of the query it is not easy but my best guess is that you don't need `AS T` in your code

Comment: What is T1? Does that table exist in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your query to be using  preprepared statement

```
Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(sql_auth,login,password); 


sql2 = " SELECT COUNT(*)  CNT FROM ( SELECT UPPER(SOURCECODE)  as SRCCODE
       FROM  T1 WHERE  (PRODUCTTYPE LIKE '%card%') 
       AND ORDER_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,?) AND   
       CONVERT(DATETIME,?)   
       AND (UPPER(SOURCECODE) IS NOT NULL)  GROUP BY            
       UPPER(SOURCECODE)) AS T";

PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement(sql2);

ps.setDate(1, ddet.getStartDate());
ps.setDate(2, ddet.getEndDate());
```

Check the toString of your query if you want

```
 ps.toString();
```

Execute your query

```
     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```